# Display columns based on conditions of multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database

My aim is to print the mail id, address and the pet type by giving conditions where status = 'yes' in donation_status table, id of pet_details = pet_id of donor and pet_id of recipient and id of members = member_id of donor ad member_id = recipient.

In simple terms , I want to display the details of donor and recipient as well as the type of pet donated

[image: Tables of members details and donor details]

[image: Tables of recipient details, pet details and donation status details]

Figure 1: Tables - members and donor
Figure 2: Tables - recipient, donation_status, pet_details

The query I tried was
`select members.mail_id,members.address,pet_details.type from members,pet_details,donor,recipient,donation_status where members.id in (select pet_id from members,pet_details,donor,recipient,donation_status where status = 'yes' in (select member_id from donor,members,pet_details,donor,recipient where donor.member_id = recipient.member_id in (select pet_id from members,pet_details,donor,recipient where pet_id.donation_status = id.pet_details)))`

The error I got was,

ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'donor'

Comment: Copy text, not images. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry I don't know.. I will update the post soon with the error in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to perform this query is with a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT m1.mail_id AS donor, m1.address AS `donor address`, m2.mail_id AS recipient, m2.address AS `recipient_address`, pet_details.type as `pet type`
FROM members m1
JOIN donor ON donor.member_id = m1.id
JOIN recipient ON recipient.pet_id = donor.pet_id
JOIN donation_status ON donation_status.pet_id = donor.pet_id
JOIN members m2 ON m2.id = recipient.member_id
JOIN pet_details ON pet_details.id = donor.pet_id
WHERE donation_status.status = 'yes'
```

Output (it seems a member donated a dog to themselves):

```
donor               donor address           recipient               recipient_address       pet type    
mn.sha222@gmail.com Gandhinagar Coimbatore  mn.sha222@gmail.com     Gandhinagar Coimbatore  dog
```